# Puppeteer and react-router (BrowserRouter)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, puppeteer

In a non react-router application I tested the status code with this simple code:

```
const response = await page.goto(url, { timeout: 60000, waitUntil: ['networkidle0','domcontentloaded'] })
assert.equal(response.status(), 200)
```

but in a react-router application (using BrowserRouter), I get this exception

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
```

I didn't find much information on how to use Puppeteer with the history API. 
How could I solve this issue?

More info:

- It's a client application (Symphony) and I use that code inside a jest test to simualte a browser call
- puppeteer: 2.1.1
- react-router: 5.1.2

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to really help you. Is it a server or client rendered application? Does it work when you request it from a browser or with curl?

Comment: @JonSakas It's a client application and I use that code inside a jest test to simualte a browser call

Comment: Thanks, if you are getting a 500 from the web server, it's never hitting the router. Your server is not configured to deliver the index.html file on some route.

Comment: @JonSakas Sorry, another info: the index.html is a `.twig` managed by Symfony. I suppose that route is configureted correctly because the applicatoion works fine. Only the test fails

Comment: I would double check the route you are requesting and make sure its correct. If it is, look at the server logs. The PHP server should hopefully tell you why it cannot process the request and deliver a 500 back.